# Java GUI: How do I have more than one button on a row using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, button, row, gridbaglayout

I'm fairly new to java and I'm having a problem trying to put more than one button on a row,
at the moment I'm adding both buttons to the panel, but I don't know how to separate their x locations, i.e. they are both being added directly on to of each other.

Do I need to create a new layout or can I find a solution using what I have at the moment?

```
public class Question1 {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame("Simple Submit Cancel Form");
        f.init();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    MyFrame(String title){
    super(title);
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private GridBagConstraints cText = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagConstraints cButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();

    void init(){
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(gbLayout);
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,20,10,20));
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        cText.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        cText.weightx = 0.0;
        cText.gridx = 0;
        cText.gridy = 0;

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
        gbLayout.setConstraints(tf,cText);
        mainPanel.add(tf);

        cButton.gridwidth = 4;
        cButton.weightx = 0.0;
        cButton.gridx = 0;
        cButton.gridy = 1;

        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(b,cButton);
        mainPanel.add(b);
        b = new JButton("Cancel");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(b,cButton);
        mainPanel.add(b);



        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) ;
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just increment the gridx value:

```
    JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
    // gbLayout.setConstraints(b,cButton);
    mainPanel.add(b, cButton);
    b = new JButton("Cancel");
    cButton.gridx++;
    // gbLayout.setConstraints(b,cButton);
    mainPanel.add(b, cButton);
```

Also you need to use the constraints created when adding your component to the grid bag layout using container.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Question1 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyFrame f = new MyFrame("Simple Submit Cancel Form");
      f.init();
   }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
   private static final int GAP = 2;

   MyFrame(String title) {
      super(title);
   }

   private JPanel mainPanel;
   private GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();

   void init() {
      mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.setLayout(gbLayout);
      mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
      this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP);
      gbc.gridwidth = 2;
      gbc.weightx = 1.0;
      gbc.weighty = 1.0;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;

      JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);

      mainPanel.add(tf, gbc);

      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 1;

      JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
      mainPanel.add(b, gbc);
      b = new JButton("Cancel");
      gbc.gridx++;
      mainPanel.add(b, gbc);

      this.pack();
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy response,  I was wondering though if the buttons could be on the same row (i.e. the same y value)?

Comment: @user3352349: oops, you're right. It's the x-value that needs to be incremented.

Comment: @user3352349: also use the constraints when adding the components. Read the tutorial which Google will help you find.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Question1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame("Simple Submit Cancel Form");
        f.init();
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    MyFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private GridBagConstraints cText = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagConstraints cButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    private GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();

    void init() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(gbLayout);
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        cText.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        cText.weightx = 0.0;
        cText.gridx = 0;
        cText.gridy = 0;

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(20);
        gbLayout.setConstraints(tf, cText);
        mainPanel.add(tf);

        cButton.gridwidth = 4;
        cButton.weightx = 0.0;
        cButton.gridx = 0;
        cButton.gridy = 1;

        JPanel demoPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
        gbLayout.setConstraints(demoPanel, cButton);
        demoPanel.add(b);
        b = new JButton("Cancel");
        // gbLayout.setConstraints(b,cButton);
        demoPanel.add(b);

        mainPanel.add(demoPanel);

        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have just put the two buttons inside a JPanel and put the JPanel inside the GridBagLayout Panel !

Comment: Accept it as answer, if it helped ya :)

Comment: Not a perfect solution at all... but temporarily solves your problem. Still not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what would be your suggestion Crystal Meth?

Comment: @CrystalMeth Why not recommended ?

Comment: I would always suggest using the GridBagConstraints for working with the GridBagLayout. Check out the answer posted by HoverCraft Full Of Eels.
@Itachi: What if we have to do this same thing with many such buttons in different parts of the table? It will require to many Panels.

Comment: @CrystalMeth I don't know, compound layouts is a good approach, so long as you were adding each row to the panel. The only problem with this approach would be the fact that the columns wouldn't match up...IMHO